# The interface firmware FAILED to reset/halt the target MCU

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32cubemx

I want to connect my simple STM32F401RET6 Nucleo to a computer for firmware updates via the USB port, not through STLINK pins and SWD. When I try to connect the USB cable, I receive this error message:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWpJk.png)

Before this board all of the board were stitched. When I try to start the debugger in Cubeide, I get this message:

```
Starting server with the following options:
        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
        Logging Level              : 1
        Listen Port Number         : 61234
        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
        SWD Debug                  : Enabled
        InitWhile                  : Enabled

Target no device found

Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: No device found on target.
```

Attempting to debugging in CubeProg despite the above gives me a message that my STLINK not connected to the target:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR5Tw.png)

This how the board looks like now, maybe this is hardware problem? Or do I need to switch cable USB to firmware nucleo?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZjK8.jpg)

I started my test project with CubeMX and it gives the same message. I put all of the jumpers and tried to put a jumper on BOOT0/BOOT1. Debug mode puts on both OpenOCD and GDBServer, nothing is working.

Comment: Your English is unfortunately hard to keep up with, to the point where I don't even understand what you mean. I tried to edit the post and fix some grammar mistakes, but there are still parts of the question which I just don't understand: "all of the board were stitched", "do I need to switch cable USB to firmware nucleo?", "Debug mode puts on both OpenOCD and GDBServer". Please clarify further.

Comment: A _picture_ of _text_?  Why not just post the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ST-Link has different connection modes to cope with different hardware implementations and debug scenarios.  You should change the mode to determine what works.  Probably "*Connect under RESET*".

Also it will fail to connect if RDP has been enabled.

You might try to connect with the stand-alone STM32CubeProgrammer, it provides more comprehensive diagnostic information which may help.